# C# Lucene.net で　検索結果を重複なしで取得

Tags: c#, lucene

C# Lucene.net で　検索結果を重複なしで取得したいのですが、どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？　サンプルやヒントでも結構なのでご教示をお願い致します。